# Clear cache in Lumen Framework

Tags: php, lumen

I want to clear cache in lumen framework. I thought the command line is the same with Laravel command. I tried to run this:

```
php artisan clear:cache
```

but it giving error php artisan
Could not open input file: `artisan.`

Need help!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumen doesn't have the `artisan` command. From the [Lumen Cache documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache) head over to the Laravel Cache documentation where there's a section [Removing Items From The Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#removing-items-from-the-cache). From that page:

> You may clear the entire cache using the flush method:
>
> `Cache::flush();`

Answer (score -3):

You should try:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: It is best if you explain your answer, otherwise you will get downvoted.